# rotate Object towards another in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

I have already this function from [this question](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/585035/lookat-2d-equivalent-.html). I changed the sign of the rotation:

```
 void rotateBotConnector()
{
    Vector3 diff = (player.transform.position - botConnector.transform.position).normalized;
    float rot_z = Mathf.Atan2(diff.y, diff.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    botConnector.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, -(rot_z - 90f));
}
```

But the problem is, that now my object follows the player on the XZ plane but when the rotation reaches a certain degree, left or right, the object stops to rotate towards my player.

For better understanding: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3259v.jpg

Comment: Are you trying to do this in 2D or 3D?

Comment: What exactly do you mean "the object stops to rotate towards my player" ? i dont understand

Comment: http://imgur.com/vWaqc31 I mean like this, and I want to rotate my object only in the z-axis

Comment: Dont you need to remove the `-90f ` from the last line?
Instead of `.....Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, -(rot_z - 90f));` 
this `Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, -(rot_z));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use:

```
var target : Transform;

transform.LookAt(Vector3(target.transform.position.x, target.transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
```

It seems a lot easier than using euler. This way you look at target's x & y but transform your z.

Also I'm no expert with euler but it seems like it is limited to a 90 degree turn and I think this may be the reason why:

```
Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, -(rot_z - 90f));
```

Comment: thanks, this worked, after I fixed the rotation from blender to unity

Comment: No problem!

By the way I snagged this from http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/232753/transformlookat-problem.html. Simple google search of "transform.LookAt problem".

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have absolute necessity to rotate via angles maybe you'd rather go with manipulating the forward vector of the object, it's easier to understand the logic this way:

```
void rotateBotConnector()
{
    Vector3 targetForwad = botConnector.transform.position - player.transform.position;
    targetForward.y= 0f;
    targetForward.Normalize(); // <-- this is very expensive function try avoid using it whenever possible
    botConnector.forward = Vector3.Lerp(botConnector.forward, targetForward, Time.deltaTime));
}
```

once again, if you are short on cpu cycles you may want to go for trying to calculate angles instead of vectors. But in most cases this is ok. (the code needs a spell checking)