# How to rotate an object towards where the mouse is in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, mouseevent

I have a little problem with the player.

I've implemented a code that makes the object move slowly toward the mouse's position.

**The problem:** That the object does not rotate, I want it to rotate, to be pointed towards the mouse.

```
private Vector3 _target;
public Camera Camera;
public bool FollowMouse;
public bool ShipAccelerates;
public float ShipSpeed = 2.0f;

public void OnEnable()
{
    if (Camera == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Camera not set");
    }
}

public void Update()
{
    if (FollowMouse || Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        _target = Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        _target.z = 0;
    }

    var delta = ShipSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    if (ShipAccelerates)
    {
        delta *= Vector3.Distance(transform.position, _target);
    }

    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, _target, delta);
}
```

I would be grateful if someone would help me.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try making this into a [mcve], please! <3

Comment: so no one knows...))

Comment: I did it myself, thanks

Comment: Oh, someone knows the answer. Just not me <3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotate an object towards mouse position and fire some bullet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46565890/rotate-an-object-towards-mouse-position-and-fire-some-bullet)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rotate Object towards another in Unity3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759841/rotate-object-towards-another-in-unity3d)